# wine: command not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine

I am not able to install Windows programs by using Wine in Ubuntu terminal. I have installed Wine through Software center. When I try to install a program in the terminal (i. e. 1StarCraft-Setup.exe`) shows me:

```
No command 'wine' found, did you mean:
Command 'xine' from package 'xine-ui' (universe)
Command 'line' from package 'util-linux' (main)
Command 'twine' from package 'twine' (universe)
Command 'wipe' from package 'wipe' (universe)
Command 'win' from package 'wily' (universe)
Command 'wing' from package 'wing' (universe)
wine: command not found
```

And after

> dpkg-query -l wine*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  wine           <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine-amd64     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine-binfmt    <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  wine-developme 1.9.6-1ubunt all          Windows API implementation - stan
un  wine-gecko     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  wine-gecko2.21 2.21-0ubuntu amd64        Microsoft Windows compatibility l
ii  wine-gecko2.21 2.21-0ubuntu i386         Microsoft Windows compatibility l
un  wine-i386      <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine-mono      <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  wine-mono0.0.8 0.0.8-0ubunt all          Microsoft Windows compatibility l
ii  wine-stable    2.0.1~xenial amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS
ii  wine-stable-am 2.0.1~xenial amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS
ii  wine-stable-i3 2.0.1~xenial i386         WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS
un  wine1.0        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.2        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.3        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.4        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.4-amd64  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.4-i386   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.5        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.5-amd64  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  wine1.5-i386   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  wine1.6        1:1.6.2-0ubu amd64        Microsoft Windows Compatibility L
ii  wine1.6-amd64  1:1.6.2-0ubu amd64        Microsoft Windows Compatibility L
ii  wine1.6-i386:i 1:1.6.2-0ubu i386         Microsoft Windows Compatibility L
ii  wine32-develop 1.9.6-1ubunt i386         Windows API implementation - 32-b
un  wine32-develop <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  wine64-develop 1.9.6-1ubunt amd64        Windows API implementation - 64-b
un  wine64-develop <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  winetricks     0.0+20141009 all          Microsoft Windows Compatibility L
```

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg-query -l wine\*`?

Comment: Thanks. What's the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/wine` and `dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/wine`?

Comment: Hi, I removed totally Wine and Playonlinux, then I have installed latest Wine version  `wine-2.0.1` and it seems working now

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) once it it reopened and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go back into the software centre and verify that wine was actually installed. The error message seems to indicate that it did not install (at all or correctly). If you can't get it installed through software centre try installing it from the command line. Open a terminal and type `sudo apt install wine-stable winetricks` for the stable version or `sudo apt install wine-development winetricks` for a more up-to-date (but possible unstable) version.